# Types of black hole formation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, structure-formation

NASA says:

> Stellar black holes form when the center of a very massive star collapses in upon itself.

There, stars usually grow and collapse by the accretion of gas.

[This](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature02448) paper ("Formation of massive black holes through runaway collisions in dense young star clusters") seems to indicate that star mergers could have the same effect.

Then there are Primordial black holes, which may have formed through gravitational collapse in dense regions in the very early universe.

Are there other processes that lead a region of space to become a black hole?

Comment: According to [arXiv:1809.01177](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.01177) and [arXiv:1911.05791](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.05791), nobody knows how the supermassive black holes at the centers of spiral galaxies formed, but you could mine those papers for ideas.

Comment: BH can also form from [fifth force](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09915)

Comment: collapse of defects, but that can be classified as PBH